# Trying to query a limit of 100 orders that are broken up into multiple records based on the item

Tags: soql, governorlimits, dynamic-soql, soql-injection, async-soql

I need some assistance with creating a query that will get all the records that correspond to the first 100 orders. For example the table looks something like this:

[image: Order Number OrderNumber1]

I know I can use GROUP BY grab the 100 orders but I don't know how I would then get all of the records within each order. I thought of then querying each order but that would exceed the governor limit(and is probably not a good idea anyway.

This code is already live and wasn't supposed to be more than a 100 records a day but just got a batch of over 100 this hour and broke my code... ANY assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not really sure about your usecase but can't you use inner query to get the related records. e.g. Get all the contacts associated with the first 100 Accounts.

[Select Id, name, (Select Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account LIMIT 100];

Comment: You should edit your post with a description of what the use case is. What is the code doing? Then we may be able to provide more specific feedback.